# Mandatory fields with SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm building a Sitecore powershell script where I'm using Read-Variable to read a few fields. I have added the `Mandatory=$true` on all of them and it only works for single-line fields but not for droptree ones. Anyone know how I can make it mandatory?

Here is my script:

```powershell
$item = Get-Item master:\content\home 
$result = Read-Variable -Parameters `    @{ Name = "token"; Value="Token"; Title="Value to be replaced"; Tooltip="Value to be replaced"; Placeholder="Inform what text you want to replace"; Mandatory=$true},
@{ Name = "replaceWith"; Value="Replace With"; Title="New value"; Tooltip="New Value"; Placeholder="Inform the new value"; Mandatory=$true}, 
@{ Name = "item"; Title="Select the root item. It will apply to all it's descendants"; Root="/sitecore/content/"; Mandatory=$true} `
-Description "This Dialog shows less editors, it doesn't need tabs as there is less of the edited variables" `
-Title "Initialise various variable types (without tabs)" -Width 500 -Height 480 -OkButtonName "Proceed" -CancelButtonName "Abort"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

You are not using **DropTree** but **DropLink**. I don't think you can set null value for **DropLink** type. It has always some value (clearing it on client side input won't change anything)

*Read more because there is a solution for that*

### Why Mandatory is not working

Mandatory field should work fine anyway. The reason your value for `$item` variable is never null/empty is fact that you are assigning default value at the beginning

```powershell
$item = Get-Item master:\content\home
```

Change it to

```powershell
$item = $null
```

in your initial implementation and you will see that validation with `Mandatory` parameter work, though this field will not be **DropLink** anymore, it is `SingleLineText` now (I am not sure, maybe we should report this to SPE team?). 
[image]

### How to solve the problem

Default field used in you case is **DropLink**. We have to declare that we want to use **DropTree** explicitly.

**Steps:**

- Add Additional parameter `editor="DropTree"` to your item variable
- Switch `Root` parameter name to `Source`

From now on you can set empty value for your item selector.

**Complete example:**

In this example you can see how to use `Mandatory` parameter and `-Validator` switch at the same time.

```powershell
$item = Get-Item "master:\content\home"
$item = $null
$result = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "token"; Value = "Token"; Title = "Value to be replaced"; Tooltip = "Value to be replaced"; Placeholder = "Inform what text you want to replace"; Mandatory = $true },
    @{ Name = "replaceWith"; Value = "Replace With"; Title = "New value"; Tooltip = "New Value"; Placeholder = "Inform the new value"; Mandatory = $true },`
    @{ Name = "item"; editor="DropTree";Title = "Select the root item. It will apply to all it's descendants"; Root = "/sitecore/content/"; Mandatory = $true  } `
    -Description "This Dialog shows less editors, it doesn't need tabs as there is less of the edited variables" `
    -Title "Initialise various variable types (without tabs)" -Width 500 -Height 480 `
    -OkButtonName "Proceed" -CancelButtonName "Abort" `
    -Validator {
        $itemVariable = $variables.item.Value
        if ($itemVariable.ID -eq "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}")
        {
            $variables.item.Error = "Please select different root item"
        }
}
```

[image]

## Summary

Validator feature is available for SPE 4.2+

**Links**

- More info about Validator:
  https://gist.github.com/AdamNaj/37ad58e1a9350604e4815ca586acf39e
- ReadVariable documentation:
  https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Read-Variable.html

Comment: hi Alan
I'm probably missing something silly here. I have updated the item section to be like this: 
 @{ Name = "item"; Title="Select the root item. It will apply to all it's descendants"; Root="/sitecore/content/WAL"; Validator= { 
        if($rootItem -eq $null)
        {
            $variables.item.Error = "Please select root item"
        }
} } `

$Variable:item

If I leave it blank it will show the last one selected but will not show the error message.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Diego my answer has been updated.

Comment: I tested and it works with this new example. thanks Alan!